# why is the clickable area of a range input much vertically wider than expected

Tags: html, css

The clickable area (track) of a range input is much vertically wider than expected on my chrome (version 102.0.5005.63).

But it is correct on code snippet.

Is it a chome bug?

```html
<div id="div_1" style="background-color:rgb(200,200,200)">
    <input type="range" id="sld_1" min="1" max="100" value="100" style="width:100px">
</div>
```

Comment: If you pasted just that code on your page, does it behave as expected?  I am wondering if there is some underlying CSS conflict ..

Comment: This snippet you've included doesn't demonstrate any unexpected behavior. I'm not sure how you expect us to debug it if you're not able to replicate it for us.

Comment: Guys, thanks for replying. I think I knew the answer (it has been posted below). The problem seems some subtle.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. It seems a bug of chome's DevTools.

The above problem only occurs when the emulated touch of the DevTools is enabled.

On a real touch screen (of an android mobile phone), it acts normally.